# Как избежать двойного пролистывания в fullpage.js и ошибок в нем?

Tags: javascript, fullpage, плагин

Подскажите, на сайте установлен `fullpage.js` для постраничного скролла. Работает везде норм, но если использовать трекпад, то если его не удерживать, то он пролистывает по две секции и это совсем не хорошо..Как можно избежать этой беды?
Может опцию в настройке нужно какую-то включить или еще что-то...

И еще, как избежать дергания и ошибки в консоле с тем же `fullpafe.js`
Все работает отлично, но если использовать на маке скажем трекпад или даже протсо в хроме открыть девтулс и выбрать какое-то мобильной устройство, то вылезает ошибка в консоли и страницы просто дергаются при пролистывании. Ошибка вот такая

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive
```

Я видел подобный вопрос вот здесь  https://toster.ru/q/605289 , но решения применимого именно к fullpage.js не нашел. Кто может подсказать,как избавиться от этих проблем?

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы пример привели, где эта проблема воспроизводится.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись. Проблема решена. Просто правильно настройки нужно было выставить при инициализации.-)